# How to draw a graph in android like Wifi Analyzer App?

Tags: android, android-layout, graphics, canvas

Hi I'm trying to develop a Field Test Application and i've to retrieve information like signal strength of neighboring cells.

So my question is:

> How can I display a graph with the different neighboring cells on
>   X-axis and the signal strength on Y-axis in real time? An example
>   [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=fr).

I've already got 5 or 6 neighboring cells and for each one his signal strength.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Is it getting the strength vs. neighboring cells, or is your issue displaying it? If you already have the data you can probably just plot it on a Canvas

Comment: thks for ur comment. I want to get the strength vs. neighboring and of course display it after. I've already the data so the problem is how to plot it on canvas as u said!!!

Comment: If you've never used the Canvas before, this is a good place to start: http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/06/drawing-with-canvas-in-android.html  -- And if you already have the data, just loop through the points and draw them (circles, lines through them, etc.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rather drawning the graph your self manually using Canvas, You can use Chart Engine Libraries available and that will be much easier to do also.

Like [AchartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/content/demo.html),[ChartDroid](http://code.google.com/p/chartdroid/wiki/Screenshots),[aFreeChart](https://code.google.com/p/afreechart/),[MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

For 3D Chart [Charts4J](http://code.google.com/p/charts4j/)

> How can I display a graph with the different neighboring cells on
>   X-axis and the signal strength on Y-axis in real time?

I have used aChart Engine for the same in one of my application. There is a complete API demo available with the library so it will be pretty easy to understand how to use that.

Comment: I'd like to add [aFreeChart](https://code.google.com/p/afreechart/), which is a port of jFreeChart, to the list.

Comment: Can anyone tell me if any of these libraries contains any thing related to Bell Curves graph ? I wasn't able to find one.

Comment: My choice is [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). It includes a realtime example too and allows cross-platform development between Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which type of graph you want to develop because there are different types at your link. But I've developed a real time line graph in android. I'm using canvas for drawing lines.

```
public class GraphView extends View
{
    ...
    private final Rect rect = new Rect();
    private final Paint linePaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint backgroundPaint = new Paint();
    private float[] points;

    public GraphView(final Context context, final AttributeSet aSet)
    {
        super(context, aSet);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas)
    {
        if (points == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        canvas.drawLines(points, linePaint);
        rect.set((int) (xIndex * xScale), 0, (int) (xIndex * xScale + 5), getHeight());
        canvas.drawRect(rect, backgroundPaint);
    }
...
}
```

You can easily position/size your rect according to your needs. I didn't wrote the calculations of xIndex and xScale. The points array is the one which your values will be written.

But beware, in android lines are drawn with pairs, there is no 'point' structure as I know.

I mean [1, 0.25, 2, 0.45] draws a line between x1= 1, y1=0.25 and x2=2, y2= 0.45

Also you can trigger draw by postInvalidate()

[postInvalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29)
[onDraw (Canvas canvas)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use AChartEngine rather than drawing to canvas.
You can download the library, javadocs and a demo application [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/downloads/list).

There are tutorials on youtube on getting started with AChartEngine.

You can use line charts with the area below chart filled with a color or not filled for copying the functionality in the first screenshots you provided.