# Export chart as pdf in Android

Tags: android

In my application, I am creating a chart to display on screen, Now I want to save this chart as PDF to my phone. Suggest me how can I do this? How to get Image of it and save to PDF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create Chart using [Any Chart Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101666/how-to-draw-a-graph-in-android-like-wifi-analyzer-app/11150546#11150546).
2. Create Bitmap of that ChartView

   > ```
   > mChartView.buildDrawingCache();
   > Bitmap bm = mChartView.getDrawingCache();
   > ```
3. Create [PDF with Image](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/841.html) and pass that Bitmap using iText

Comment: Create Chart using "Any Chart" Library.  Please do not use  MPAndroidChart , it use android.view.GestureDetector so it will crash outside the UI context.

Comment: I have already imolemented MPAndroidChart PhilJay, is their any posibility I can implement this in PDF