# Editing/Painting on Canvas and see result "immediately"

Tags: android, android-canvas

I am writing fractal generator for Android.

Code is available here:

https://github.com/nmmmnu/MandelDroid

But question part is this:

```
@Override
public void run() {
        if (!_holder.getSurface().isValid())
            continue;

        _canvas = _holder.lockCanvas();

        // generate fractal here, use this for write:
        while(...){
            int a = calcPixelColor();
            _paint.setARGB(0xFF, a, a, a);
            _canvas.drawPoint(x, y, _paint);
        }

        _holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(_canvas);

}
```

However if I do it this way, the whole picture is shown when all fractal is generated. I tried this, but result was awful:

```
    if (++__counter > 10000){
        __counter = 0;

        _holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(_canvas);
        _canvas = _holder.lockCanvas();
    }
```

Any easy way how to show the pixels as soon as they are "painted"?

Comment: See them where?   The canvas does draw each pixel immediately, to whatever the backing store is.  If the backing store is a SurfaceHolder or the like, you simple have to unlock and post more often (perhaps on a timer drawing X points per time slice).

Comment: show on the screen. this is what i am doing with second snipped, but screen flickr and have missing "lines"

Comment: You should perform all your drawings inside the `onDraw()` event. As in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11236574/2649012)

Comment: probably i am missing something, but if I do so, it will block for 30-40 sec until is repainted. tried something similar, worked on 4.0 and 4.2 and did not worked on 4.4. but in all cases blocked everything - definitely not the right way

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/optimizing-view.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did lots of changes that may be seen in the repository, but main thing is I switched from drawing on the canvas:

```
_canvas = _holder.lockCanvas();
```

to something "easier" - drawing on a bitmap.

Then I implemented onDraw() as follows:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       canvas.drawBitmap(_image, 0, 0, _paint2);
}
```

To display from time to time I did:

```
    if (__counter++ > COUNTER_MAX){
        __counter = 0;

        this.postInvalidate();
    }
```

And finally when the thread that generates the fractal is finished, i added one more invalidate

```
@Override
public void run() {
    // generate fractal here

    this.postInvalidate();
}
```